# c++ SIGABRT in struct destructor in multithreading app

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix, sigabrt

I'd need a hand in solving today's multithreading mystery.

I have an application that has a mediator, say:

```
class Mediator{
    ConfigMgr * mgr;
    ....
    Config getConfig(){
    return mgr->getConfig();
    };
};
```

ConfigMgr is properly initialized, there's no problem with it whatsoever. It consist of, amongst other things, a Config blueprint, which is a struct that has some booleans and std::strings:

```
struct Config{
    std::string param1;
    std::string param2;
    ....
}

class ConfigMgr {
    Config blueprint;

    Config getConfig(){
        Lock l(mtx); //wrapper on POSIX mutex and lock, works as expected
        refreshConfig(); // some stuff that might alter Config blueprint
        return config;
    }

}
```

Finally, I have multiple working threads that once in a while might need to call
`mediator->getConfig().param1;`

The problem is that every now and then my app crashes with SIGABRT. From what I've been able to determine, it crashes on double-delete of string in Config's destructor:
`Config::~Config()`
The struct has no methods written by me.

I can't track the root cause. My Config struct is always passed by copy, not reference. I think every thread should have his own copy of Config ever since invocation of ConfigMgr::getConfig(). This construction should be thread-safe, but there clearly is some sort of race condition. Do you guys have any advice?

Comment: Is it possible that the `ConfigMgr` instance owning the `Config` object is deleted twice?

Comment: Is `getConfig` the **only** API from your working threads to `ConfigMgr`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: ConfigMgr is not deleted. What I mean, it is only deleted during program shutdown, it can't be deleted during runtime.

icepack: actually, configMgr has three more methods threads might call, all are protected using Lock/Mutex and all return sole string or int. I skipped that since I though it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been hit by this. The important things to remember are:

1. std::string shares its char* buffer when it's copied.
2. std::string is not designed for multi-threading.

Therefore you are hitting multiple std::strings in different threads trying to delete the same  buffer, that they think should be deleted due to reference counting variables not being updated correctly.

You're probably going to have to be more explicit about the string copies you want, and define a copy constructor for the Config object.

Comment: You mean if you have a global string object which is assigned during startup (while the process is single-threaded) and later multiple threads make copies of it (but nothing is making changes to the shared string instance) then this is not safe?  That's terrible.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've verified the first point, using valgrind and string copies, the second is obvious given the history of threading in C++. (Which means some implementations might be thread-safe, but it isn't required).

Comment: @BenVoigt When the string is copied in two threads at the same time, they may not increase the reference count sufficiently, then the buffer may be freed early (allowing reference to freed memory), similarly if multiple threads free the string copies at the same time, they may multiply try to free the buffer - AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look through the Standard, and it's badly underspecified whether non-mutating functions are allowed to modify shared memory locations.  In the current state of non-specification, even the threading library isn't necessarily usable from multiple threads.  Definitely something I hope they address in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot. I solved the issue by creating Copy Constructor to struct Config, which I secured using mutex and I assured that buffer is recreated, not shared.